# Associative property of convolution

Tags: convolution, associativity

Consider the following sequences:

$x_{1}(n) = A$ (a constant), $x_{2}(n) = u(n)$, $x_{3}(n) =\delta(n)-\delta(n-1)$.

($\circledast$ stands for linear convolution)

If I perform the operation $x_{2}\circledast (x_{3}\circledast x_{1})$, the value I am getting is $0$, where as if I perform $(x_{2}\circledast x_{3})\circledast x_{1}$ the value I am getting is A.

Since Convolution is associative, why are the answers different?

My approach: In general, assuming $x_{1}(n)$, $x_{2}(n)$, $x_{3}(n)$ exists from $-\infty$ to $\infty$,

$$x_{2}\circledast (x_{3}\circledast x_{1})=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x_2(k).x_{3}\circledast x_{1}(n-k)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x_2(k)\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}x_3(l)x_1(n-k-l)$$

Let $m=n-k-l$,

$$=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}x_2(k)x_3(l)x_1(n-k-l)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}x_2(k)x_3(n-m-k)x_1(m)$$

$$=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}x_{2}\circledast x_{3}(n-m)x_1(m)=(x_{2}\circledast x_{3})\circledast x_{1}$$

Hence I feel Convolution is associative even if the functions are of infinite lengths. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: are this function over $\mathbb{N}$? Can you show us your computation? is it $u$ a generic function?

Comment: u is unit step function defined as u(n) = 1 if n $\geqslant 0$ , and 0 elsewhere

Comment: For [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) convolution is *not* associative unless the distributions involved have compact support. That fails here, since both $x_1$ and $x_2$ have non-compact support.

Comment: @md2perpe, I did not understand the exact meaning given in that page. Can you explain in a simpler way if possible?

Comment: The page was more a link to what *distributions* mean than meant to give an explanation of this phenomena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have skipped one step, the one in red:
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x_2(k) \, x_3(n-m-k) \, x_1(m) \\
= \color{red}{
    \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x_2(k) \, x_3(n-m-k) \, x_1(m)
} \\
= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x_{2} \circledast x_{3}(n-m) \, x_1(m)
$$

Under what conditions are you allowed to swap the order of summations? Are they fulfilled here?

Comment: Order of summations can be swapped if the involved sequences are summable (individually), and hence the associative property holds. In my question, $x_1(n)$, and $x_2(n)$ are not summable and this property does not hold. Thanks.